# Use Wii Remote and Arduino to emulate a keyboard for Windows 10?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, windows

Is it possible to use an Arduino to communicate with a Wii Remote, connect the Arduino to a Windows 10 computer, and have the Wii Remote inputs be translated into keyboard keys for Windows 10?

I've used several Wii Remote Windows 10 apps, such as WiiUSoft, but I find such programs very unreliable.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: ¿What is the purpose of that?

Comment: To use a Wii Remote as a simulated keyboard for Windows 10.

Comment: Not easily with an Uno. It can be done if you change the USB interface firmware. A Leonardo would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino Leonardo and Arduino Micro (as well as other third-party boards, such as the Teensy and the chipKIT Lenny) can be directly programmed to emulate a keyboard.  There are examples in the IDE that show how to do this.

It is possible with an Uno, but that requires replacing the firmware on the USB interface's ATMega32U4 chip with special HID firmware. This is a non-standard setup, though, and may make programming of the Arduino through the USB port impossible.  So I wouldn't recommend doing that, and would instead go for a board that can directly emulate a keyboard.

There are plenty of tutorials on the web for connecting a Wii Remote with an Arduino, (including [a library](https://hardwarefun.com/projects/wiiremote)), so couple that with the examples in the IDE and a suitable board and you are good to go.  From then on it's just a Simple Matter of Programming...